# Adding A Background Image In XAML

Tags: xaml

I am very new to XAML code, but I want to try and code a personal program. I have started with XAML but anything I add does not show up. Here is my code:

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="7,725,0,0" Height="36" Width="91" BorderBrush="Orange" Foreground="Orange" FontFamily="BankGothic Md Bt"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366" Source="C:/Users/Flynn/Desktop/BG.gif" Visibility="Visible"/>


    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The button nor the image is showing up when I run the program. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To set a background to a grid, just keep your image in Images folder and add this code inside grid

```
<Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="..\Images\background.jpg" AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Center"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

Comment: small tip make sure the grid.background is encased in open close grid brackets e.g. <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="..\Images\vector.jpg" AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Center"/>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.It works

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="36" Width="91" BorderBrush="Orange" Foreground="Orange" FontFamily="BankGothic Md Bt"/>
    <Image Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/super.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

You should define the background property like this

You must add in to App.xaml (for color resource)

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="BlueViolet"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Image source have to be in your solution (application)

Comment: Margin values of button (Margin="7,725,0,0").You set top value 725.If your window height value from less than 725 so your button doesn't show.

Comment: I tried this and now I have a colored background! :D Thanks for the help. You put super.png but where do I place that image?